# Expressing row space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am a confusion about some basic linear algebra here.

When we determine a basis of the row space of an $m\times n$ matrix $A$, do we write the vectors in this basis as row vectors or column vectors? For me it seemed that we should write them as row vectors but I am not sure if we can write them as column vectors as well.

Comment: The row space is typically defined as the space consisting of all linear combinations *of the rows*.  I would encourage you then to write the space of linear combinations of the rows *using row vectors*.  If you insist then technically you could define things however you want and have the row space be defined as the space consisting of linear combinations of the transpose of the row vectors, or where you are agnostic to whether a vector is a row vector vs a column vector, or what-have you... and that would be fine to do.  In the end, it is your choice but you should be clear on the definition